# working with list to string in a word translator

Tags: list, scheme, racket, list-processing

I am new to scheme and am having trouble creating a relatively simple piglatin translator ((word begins with vowel add "way" to the end, begins with consonant, add all letters before first vowel + ay to the end duck -> uckday.)

(translate '(sticks and stones)) -> (ickstay andway onestay)

I believe I should have the correct solution however am having trouble processing the phrase as a list with string->list and list->string in order to properly translate each word.

```
#lang racket

(define translate
  (lambda (sentance)
    (map breakSentance sentance)))


; break down sentance string split
(define (breakSentance word)
  (string->list (listWord (string->list word))))

; break down word for vowel testing
(define (listWord word)
    (cond
      ((foundVowel (car word)) (noVowel word))
      (else (noVowel word))))

; letters that are vowels, their presence indicates how the word should be latinized
(define (foundVowel)
  (lambda (letter)
    (member letter '("aeiouy"))))


(define (startsVowel)
  (lambda (word)
    (append word '("way"))))


(define (noVowel)
  (lambda (word lets)
    (cond
      (foundVowel (car word)) (noVowel word))
    (string-join word (string-join lets '("ay")))))
```

Comment: You are confusing symbols and strings in your program. There is no a single string in it (a string is written with double quotes: `"this is a string"`). Instead you have symbols, or list of symbols, like `'(ay)`. You should understand the difference between these two datatypes and then rewrite your program.

Comment: @Renzo but why do I have "string->list: contract violation
  expected: string?" in breakSentance?

Comment: because `string->list` operates on a **string**, and you must pass a string to it. If, for instance, as it seems from your example, you call `(translate '(sticks and stones))`, then `breakSentance` will be called with the **symbols** `sticks`, `and` and `stones`.

Comment: @Renzo Ah wow I see, thank you. Stupid mistake there.